# Boost microphone volume on windows vista over max

Tags: windows-vista, audio, microphone, steam

I quite literally made an account on here to post this question. I've already tried the standard settings such as the slider that boosts your volume by 30% and I've maxed ALL the mic controls on both Steam and windows so is there a way to get more out of it because my friend can never seem to hear me well despite my having turned my settings TO THE MAX! Is it possible without purchasing new hardware or is there some software I could use?
Thanks very much,
      Clarinetking

Comment: @techie007 I have looked there but none of their answers have worked. Thank you for trying though :)

Comment: Doesn't mean it's not the same question, even if the existing answers don't work. :) Perhaps, to avoid additional close votes, edit yours to explain all you have tried already, what the results were, and how your question is different from the marked duplicate.  Otherwise, it's the same question (IMO, at least).  If you'd like newer/better answers on the existing question, consider earning [some rep.](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and placing [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.

Comment: Try another microphone, even if it's one you don't plan on using. Try turning DOWN all other inputs, so the MIC input has a greater dynamic range than the other inputs.